# Symfony's BirthdayType field: how to add labels to generated text widget?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

My Symfony form uses the [BirthdayType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html) field. Its default behaviour is to add three separate dropdowns for the month, day and year. I added the text widget option as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html#widget) in order to have three separate text input fields. My question is: how can I also generate labels for each of those input fields?

The generated HTML is:

```
   <div id="user_birthDate">
       <input type="text" id="user_birthDate_month" name="user[birthDate][month]" required="required">
       <input type="text" id="user_birthDate_day" name="user[birthDate][day]" required="required">
       <input type="text" id="user_birthDate_year" name="user[birthDate][year]" required="required">
   </div>
```

FormBuilder (excerpt):

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
 {
     $builder
        ->add('birthDate', BirthdayType::class, ['widget' => 'text'])
        ->add('next', SubmitType::class);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make a custom twig :

```
{#birthdate.html.twig !#}

{% block birthday_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
     <label> month </label>
     <input type="text" id="user_birthDate_month" name="user[birthDate][month]" required="required">

     <label> day </label>
     <input type="text" id="user_birthDate_day" name="user[birthDate][day]" required="required">

     <label> year </label>
     <input type="text" id="user_birthDate_year" name="user[birthDate][year]" required="required">

    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

and add this line in the config.yml :

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'form/birdhdate.html.twig'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add labels in the options like you did with the 'widget'

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
 {
 $builder
    ->add('birthDate', BirthdayType::class, [
         'widget' => 'text',
         'label' => 'Birthday label that you want to show',
        ])
    ->add('next', SubmitType::class);
 }
```

Also see https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#field-type-options

Comment: Thank you, but I actually want to generate a label for each of the generated text input fields, not just 1 general label